# How to open qml file in design mode?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I have created hello world application, I want to add a button to qml file:

[image]

Is it possible to open this file in WYSIWYG mode, so I can add button there?

Comment: On the left side there is a button called **Design**, press it :)

Comment: Please put at as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the design mode you must click on the **Design** button on the left side.